# How to include second partition in GRUB

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning

I have a single hard drive with two partitions, which currently looks like this:

[image: Hard drive partitions]

To keep it short and (hopefully) clear, here's what happened:

1. Way back I created two partitions as shown, and installed Ubuntu 13.04 onto `sda1`, leaving `sda2` empty
2. I later installed Ubuntu 18.04 onto `sda2`, partitioning it as shown, and moved to this as my primary OS instance
3. Since I'm not using `sda1` any more I decided to experiment with migrating back to `sda1` so that I could expand to use the whole hard drive; so I backed up `sda2` to a NAS using CloneZilla Live
4. After the backup, I restored the backup on top of `sda1`

This last step seemed to redo my GRUB configuration automatically, and it only shows me the entries for `sda1`.

Since I'm not quite ready to start working in `sda1` yet, how do I get GRUB to show me the entries for `sda2`?

Comment: First of all, run `sudo update-grub`, reboot and see what happens.

Comment: @mook765 I had tried that, and it didn't change anything for me (same GRUB menu).  As part of writing this question I experimented with adding the `boot` flag to `sda6`, and that seems to now boot automatically into `sda6` without showing GRUB.  I still need to understand how to convince GRUB to show the OS's from both partitions?

Comment: I would run boot-repair as it not only repairs broken boots but also sets up grub entries automatically: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Thanks - will take a look.